# MinecraftForge modding Send a command from the client to the server

Tags: java, minecraft

So I wanted to create a GUI for a server to make stuff easier for ppl. I created a Gui with buttons for easy use so you don't have to enter commands all the time. The button works but I didn't find any function that executes a command as the player itself. I googled around but didn't find a solution for this problem.

(btw. this obviously didn't work: `player.sendChatToPlayer("/{any command}");` (player is a EntityPlayer))

Regards Jens

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do a `Minecraft.getMinecraft().thePlayer.sendChatMessage("/Command here")`

Comment: That was easy :) I used EntityPlayer instead of EntityClientPlayerMP. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

In case you want to execute a client-side only command, you can use

`ClientCommandHandler.instance.executeCommand(Minecraft.getMinecraft().thePlayer, "/your command");`